# python text file and looping through emails to retrieve the amount of times a domain occurs

Tags: python-3.x, loops, dictionary

```
file = open("../dataFiles/mbox-short.txt", "r")
lines = file.readlines()
domDictioary = {}
for line in lines:
    for email in line.split(''):
        if "@" in email:
            words = email.split()
            for emailine in words:
                print(emailine)



file.close()
```

so ive managed to split text in the files in to  but i wanna count each domain name (hotmail) (iprimus) but i do not have a list of domain names and must locate and store them in a dictionary prehaps through a word count like len[0] past @ but unsure how i would code that

Answer (score 0):

You can use `defaultdict` from `import collections` (assume you already get email and its domain):

```
import collections
d = collections.defaultdict(int)
(for loop stuff)
    ...
    ...
         domain = {get_email_domain}
         d[domain] += 1
```

That you can get domain count; and you want to tract detail email address, you can use `collections.defaultdict(list)` to append email list as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can add all domain strings in dictionary `key`, dictionary keys are unique so it will never keep a duplicate value , you can keep on updating the `value` of `key` to get a count of individual domain string.
Create an empty dictionary before your `loop` starts.

```
count_dict = {}
#
#your nested `for` loop logic which gives domain strings
#Ex :  
#for domain in .... :

    if domain in count_dict.keys():
        count_dict[domain] = count_dict[domain] + 1
    else:
        count_dict[domain] = 1
```

This will give you a `count_dict` dictionary with `key` your domain name and `value` is the count of occurrence of respective domain.